# How to copy files from a kubernetes pod to a Google Cloud bucket programmatically

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to copy files from a **Kubernetes** pod to a **GCP Bucket**.
I can get the path of my file, but I was wondering if I want to do this programmatically using python, how can I do this.

I get my buckets using `gcsfs`. How can I copy a file in my program without using `kubectl`?

Is there anyway to do this through python.

Comment: It is not very clear. Can you share what you did/tried?

Comment: There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703610/copy-file-from-pod-to-host-by-using-kubernetes-python-client) about how to copy a file from a pod. You can download it and then use your code to upload it to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I need to agree with the comment made by @anemyte:

> There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703610/copy-file-from-pod-to-host-by-using-kubernetes-python-client) about how to copy a file from a pod. You can download it and then use your code to upload it to the bucket.

---

I see 2 possible solutions to this question:

- Use `GCS Fuse` and Python code to copy the file from your `Pod` to `GCS` bucket
- Use the Python library to connect to the GCS bucket without `gcsfuse`

---

#### Use `GCS Fuse` and Python code to copy the file from your `Pod` to `GCS` bucket

Assuming that you have a `Pod` that was configured with `GCS Fuse` and it's working correctly you can use a following code snippet to copy the files (where in `dst` you pass the mounted directory of a bucket):

> ```py
> from shutil import copyfile
> copyfile(src, dst)
> ```
>
> -- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: 123198: How can a file be copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-can-a-file-be-copied)*

---

#### Use the Python library to connect to the GCS bucket without `GCS Fuse`

As pointed by community member @anemyte, you can use the Cloud Storage client libraries to programmatically address your question:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Storage: Docs: Reference: Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)*

There is a Python code snippet that addresses the upload operation:

> ```py
> from google.cloud import storage
>
>
> def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
>     """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
>     # The ID of your GCS bucket
>     # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
>     # The path to your file to upload
>     # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
>     # The ID of your GCS object
>     # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
>
>     storage_client = storage.Client()
>     bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
>     blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
>
>     blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
>
>     print(
>         "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
>             source_file_name, destination_blob_name
>         )
>     )
> ```

Please have in mind that you will need to have appropriate permissions to use the GCS bucket. You can read more about it by following below link:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Storage: Docs Uploading objects: Prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#prereqs)*

> A side note!
>
> You can also use [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) as one of the ways to assign required permissions to your `Pod`.

---

#### Additional resources:

- *[Github.com: Maciekrb: Gcs fuse example](https://github.com/maciekrb/GCS-Fuse-sample)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Storage: Docs: GCS Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)*

It passed my mind that you could want to use Python **outside** of the `Pod` (like from your laptop) to get the file copied from the `Pod` to `GCS bucket`. I'd reckon you could follow this example:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python: Examples: Pod exec.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_exec.py)*