# How to copy file from k8 pod to GCP storage programmatically?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying my springboot application image to GCP.My springboot application processes data and creates one file.I want to copy this file to GCP Storage.Can we achieve this from Kubernetes pod to GCP Storage?

Comment: use the client library of sdk google and upload from container to GCS bucket as simple as that with java or any other language.

Comment: If you use Spring Cloud GCP, it can [write a Storage object as a `WritableResource`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.4.0/reference/html/index.html#cloud-storage).  This is reasonably portable (you can use local files or AWS S3 similarly only changing the resource URL string) and not specific to a container runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GCSFUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount GCS bucket to Kubernetes Pod as a volume.

Here is an example of Container Lifecycle Hooks to mount and unmount GCS bucket.

```
#...

securityContext:
  privileged: true
  capabilities:
    add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["gcsfuse", "-o", "nonempty,allow_other", "bucket-name", "/usr/share/nginx/bucket-data"]
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["fusermount", "-u", "/usr/share/nginx/bucket-data"]

#...
```

Reference: [MOUNTING GOOGLE CLOUD STORAGE BUCKET TO KUBERNETES POD](https://pliutau.com/mount-gcs-bucket-k8s/)

And to copy the file from your Pod to GCS bucket, use [Fabric8 Kubernetes Client](https://fabric8.io/guide/javaLibraries.html), which is described in detail [here](https://itnext.io/copy-files-to-from-pods-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-485e73335cb6).

Example code:

```
public class DownloadFileFromPod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()) {
            // Path Where to copy file to cloud storage
            Path downloadToPath = new File("path_of_gcs").toPath();
            // Using Kubernetes Client to copy file from pod
            client.pods()
                    .inNamespace("default")                         // <- Namespace of pod
                    .withName("quarkus-84dc4885b-tsck6")            // <- Name of pod
                    .file("/deployments/quarkus-1.0.0-runner.jar")  // <- Path of file inside pod
                    .copy(downloadToPath);                            // <- path where to copy downloaded file
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the [`Cloud Storage client libraries`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to programmatically achieve this.

Here is an example for [uploading files using java](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object)

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class UploadObject {
  public static void uploadObject(
      String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName, String filePath) throws IOException {
    // The ID of your GCP project
    // String projectId = "your-project-id";

    // The ID of your GCS bucket
    // String bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name";

    // The ID of your GCS object
    // String objectName = "your-object-name";

    // The path to your file to upload
    // String filePath = "path/to/your/file"

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();

    // Optional: set a generation-match precondition to avoid potential race
    // conditions and data corruptions. The request returns a 412 error if the
    // preconditions are not met.
    Storage.BlobTargetOption precondition;
    if (storage.get(bucketName, objectName) == null) {
      // For a target object that does not yet exist, set the DoesNotExist precondition.
      // This will cause the request to fail if the object is created before the request runs.
      precondition = Storage.BlobTargetOption.doesNotExist();
    } else {
      // If the destination already exists in your bucket, instead set a generation-match
      // precondition. This will cause the request to fail if the existing object's generation
      // changes before the request runs.
      precondition =
          Storage.BlobTargetOption.generationMatch(
              storage.get(bucketName, objectName).getGeneration());
    }
    storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)), precondition);

    System.out.println(
        "File " + filePath + " uploaded to bucket " + bucketName + " as " + objectName);
  }
}
```

Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68015322/18265570) with python examples for more details.

Comment: This is just a collection of links.  Is it possible to expand this answer to have a more complete explanation and setup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you need to install [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) in your springboot application image then mount your storage token in that container as configmap or secret.

In the end you can run `gsutil` like this:

```
gsutil cp source_file gs://my-bucket
```

Comment: can this be done by java code?Do u have any example where similar thing has been done?

Comment: I don't have any experience about Java, but you can do it by bash script with `gsutils`.