# store tcpdump output in another POD - kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, tcpdump

I'm using kubernetes, and I want to create tool which have the ability to do *tcpdump* on some interfaces.

The problem is that this tool is controlled from container *container_A* in *POD_A* which doesn't have *tcpdump* installed in it (and I can't change it at this point), while *tcpdump* ability can be executed from *container_B* in *POD_B* (different from *POD_A*)

So the solution I choosed is to create *tcpdump* on different container (*container_B* in *POD_B*) and then move the dump file from *container_B* to *container_A*.
For this I used something close to solution which is provided here:
[Copy file from pod to host by using kubernetes python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703610/copy-file-from-pod-to-host-by-using-kubernetes-python-client)

The problem now is that for using this solution I understand that the dump file should be closed on origin container before I copy it to the destination container. This can be causing a high disk usage on *container_A* which has a low disk space attached to it while *container_B* has a big disk space attached to it.

**I will paste the code from the link here for reference**

```py
def stream_copy_from_pod(self, pod_name, name_space, source_path, destination_path):
"""
Copy file from pod to the host.

:param pod_name: String. Pod name
:param name_space: String. Namespace
:param source_path: String. Pod destination file path
:param destination_path: Host destination file path
:return: bool
"""
command_copy = ['tar', 'cf', '-', source_path]
with TemporaryFile() as tar_buffer:
    exec_stream = stream(self.coreClient.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, pod_name, name_space,
                         command=command_copy, stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, tty=False,
                         _preload_content=False)
    # Copy file to stream
    try:
        reader = WSFileManager(exec_stream)
        while True:
            out, err, closed = reader.read_bytes()
            if out:
                tar_buffer.write(out)
            elif err:
                logger.debug("Error copying file {0}".format(err.decode("utf-8", "replace")))
            if closed:
                break
        exec_stream.close()
        tar_buffer.flush()
        tar_buffer.seek(0)
        with tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_buffer, mode='r:') as tar:
            member = tar.getmember(source_path)
            tar.makefile(member, destination_path)
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        raise manage_kubernetes_exception(e)
```

My question is can I use somehow the `exec_stream` with addaptaion provided in the example (or another `kubernetes-client` python api) and `tcpdump` command om *container_B* to stream the tcpdump straight to some tarball file (or another type of file) on *container_A*?

My assumption is that I just need to open stream `container_B` and send `command="tcpdump ..."` in a way that it will be stream the tcpdump to stdout of this container and "fetch" + "handle" this stdout from the stream into file in `container_A`, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How much of this stack is under your control?  Can you install `tcpdump` in `image_B`'s Dockerfile?  Or provide a network-accessible interface in `image_B` so that you could `HTTP POST` the completed dump file?  Or incrementally dump the stream to network-accessible storage, or a streaming messaging system like Kafka?

Comment: @DavidMaze
I can't install `tcpdump` on `image_B` but I can do incremential dump of the stream to network-accessible storage, or a streaming messaging system.    
This is actually what I'm looking for and want to understand how to do using `kubernetes` api (or maybe to use third-party package like kafka that you've mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I've decided to use Async Thrift for "management" of this operation (created client-server) rather to use python kubernetes library.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get you want to have a container that does tcpdump associated to a single application container. So that means You want two tightly coupled containers.

You are in luck because this is exactly the use-case of a multi-container `Pod`!

Put your two containers in the same `Pod` with an `EmptyDir` volume and both containers will be able to access it. This type of volume stores data on the node and is ephemeral. In my opinion this is simpler than transferring data between two separate pods that can be on two *very* distant nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention those containers are in seperate pods! so actually my probelm involves passing data from two containers in different PODS.   
One of the POD is used for management - this is where the command is called from and where the file should eventually stored and the other POD is used as Data POD is where tcpdump can be executed from.

Is there way to solve this issue in case we are talking on two different containers in two different PODS?.