# Download directory from Pod to local using Python kubernetes client

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, cp

I have been able to download a file from Pod to local using the Python Kube client. The code is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703610/copy-file-from-pod-to-host-by-using-kubernetes-python-client).
However, I don't see any example to download directory from pod to local in the official [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples).
As a workaround, I am creating a tar file of the directory in the pod. Then I am downloading the tar of the directory as a file to local and extract it.

directory -> tar -> download tar -> extract tar at local -> delete tar in pod -> delete tar in local

However, this approach involves clean-up of the temporary tar in the pod as well as local and is not very clean.
Is there any better way to download the whole directory from pod to local?

Comment: Can someone help in resolving this issue?